unclickable right portion of application in ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)
problem (24.04 LTS Noble Numbat): newly installed applications(i installed vscode,postman,myql workbench) are't working properly, they work fine when minimised, but when they are maximised,right portion of the screen inside application is like transparent, i.e, the current application looses focus and the application or desktop behind it gets the input.
steps to reproduce: upgrade to 24.04, install any new application. then this issue persists.
solutions i have tried:

some of the users said, it was problem with anydesk, but i dont have a anydesk application in my pc,

executed code --ozone-platform=wayland, it seemed like the problem was cleared but, when new window is opened the problem was same, and it didn't provide solution to either postman nor mysql workbench.



This question is similar to: Dysfunctional window controls in all my apps in Ubuntu 24.04. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have the same issue with VS Code, Chromium, and Postman. There's a github issue on the VS CODE repository, where i shared my solution: [https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/210624#issuecomment-2254510825][1]

Look on this solution from Ricardo Cruz.
It works for me.
24.04 Issue clicking window focuses on window behind/underneath

The issue seems to happen with apps that require Wayland-compatibility through Xwayland (e.g., VS Code, Steam or old GTK apps).
Until a fix comes about, the following command seems to fix the issue (during that session):
pkill -HUP mutter-x11-fram


